# Set of numbers which can not be represented as $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n$

Tags: number-theory

Let us fix a natural number $n>1$. Consider the set of natural numbers which can not be represented as  $a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_n^n$ where $a_1,...,a_n$ are non-negative integers. Is this set infinite or not?

Comment: Interesting question, I would say it is infinite for all $n\geq 2$

Comment: is n fixed or is the question for all $n$s at once?

Comment: @N.S. , I think that for n>1 set is infinite so question is for all n>1

Comment: The request for clarification/answer by Barry Carter has been flagged as *not an answer*. The comments under that post seem to have resolved the ambiguity. I think my edit makes the intended meaning clear to all future readers, but you are, of course, welcome to further improve it. Deleting Barry's post for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n=2$ you can show that primes that are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ cannot be written as the sum of two squares and that there are infinitely many of them. This shows that $\mathbb{N}\setminus S_2$ is infinite since it contains those primes.

For general $n$ you can read the Wikipedia article on [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem). The section that is relevant for your problem is the one on $G(k)$. That's the minimal number such that almost every integer can be written as the sum of $G(k)$ $k$-th powers of positive integers. With "almost every" they mean all integers except for finitely many. In particular they say that $G(k)>k+1$ for all $k>1$, so that shows that $\mathbb{N}\setminus S_k$ is also infinite.

Edit:
I am using barrycarter's notation. $S_k$ is the set of positive integers that can be written as a sum of $k$ $k$-th powers of positive integers.